# I want to order by table with below two qualities

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, sql-order-by, mysql-workbench

[image: This is the result i am getting by my query]
Above is the result i am getting by my query

•   The output shall be ordered by two different qualities
o   first, by the number of non-null rankings in descending order
o   second, by the sum of the rankings, in ascending order

[image: This is what result should look like]

Above image is for what result should look like

Server used : Mysql

this is my query and what i have tried so far any help is greatly appreciated

```
select 
    snippettitle as category
    , if(cntrank>limitnumber,null,cntrank) as counts
    ,if(viewrank>limitnumber,null,viewrank) as views
    , if(likesrank>limitnumber,null,likesrank) likes
    , if(dislikesrank>limitnumber,null,dislikesrank) dislikes
    ,if(commentrank>limitnumber,null,commentrank) comment_count 
from ( select 
            snippettitle 
            ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS cntrank 
            ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY views DESC) AS viewrank 
            ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY likes DESC) AS likesrank 
            ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY dislikes DESC) AS dislikesrank 
            ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY comment_count DESC) AS commentrank 
        from homework7a) tmp 
        where 
            (cntrank <= limitnumber 
            || viewrank <= limitnumber 
            || likesrank <= limitnumber 
            || dislikesrank <= limitnumber 
            || commentrank <= limitnumber
    ) 
order by counts desc,views desc,likes desc ,dislikes desc,comment_count desc;
```

Comment: please don't add data as image, only as **text**

Comment: see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question   posting text data as *images* is bad form, while it might be really easy for you, it makes it much harder for anyone that might want to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st condition:

> by the number of non-null rankings in descending order

can be simplified to:

> by the number of null rankings in ascending order

So I believe that you want this:

```
select *
from yourquery
order by 
  (counts is null) + (views is null) + (likes is null) + (dislikes is null) + (comment_count is null), 
  coalesce(counts, 0) + coalesce(views, 0) + coalesce(likes, 0) + coalesce(dislikes, 0) + coalesce(comment_count, 0)
```

Comment: for second condition i found one solution myself which i am posting here incase anyone need help

Comment: select *
from yourquery
order by 
  (counts is null) + (views is null) + (likes is null) + (dislikes is null) + (comment_count is null),
   COALESCE(counts,0)+ COALESCE(views,0)+ COALESCE(dislikes,0)+ COALESCE(comment_count,0)+ COALESCE(likes,0) ;